# Nested models in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I am new to Backbone and I have an issue regarding nested models. Here I have data.json where I have following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Project",
        "description" : "This is a Peugeot website",
        "url" : "http://peugeot.am",
        "images" : [
            { "image" : "A", "thumb" : "a" },
            { "image" : "B", "thumb" : "b" },
            { "image" : "C", "thumb" : "c" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name" : "Ararat",
        "description" : "This is a Ararat website",
        "url" : "http://ararat.am",
        "images" : [
            { "image" : "A", "thumb" : "a" },
            { "image" : "B", "thumb" : "b" },
            { "image" : "C", "thumb" : "c" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name" : "Procredit Bank",
        "description" : "This is a Procredit Bank website",
         "url" : "http://procredit.am",
        "images" : [
            { "image" : "A", "thumb" : "a" },
            { "image" : "B", "thumb" : "b" },
            { "image" : "C", "thumb" : "c" }
        ]
    }
]
```

In Backbone I am trying to fetch data, but I get empty array.

```
var myapp = myapp || {};

$(function () {

    myapp.Image= Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this.Img = this.get('image');
            this.Thumb = this.get('thumb');
        }
    });

    myapp.Images= Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: myapp.Image });

    myapp.Item= Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this.Name = this.get('name');
            this.Description = this.get('description');
            this.URL = this.get('url');
            this.subs = new myapp.Images(this.get('images'));
        }
    });

    myapp.Items= Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model:  myapp.Item,
        url: 'content/js/data.json',
        parse: function (resp, xhr) { return JSON.parse(resp); }
    });

    var items = new myapp.Items();
    items.fetch();
    console.log(items.toJSON());
});
```

Now, what am I doing wrong above? I need to fetch data to get JSON so to start manipulate with it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the default support is pretty lacking you would need to get the data for each nested model separately

There are library such as

https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-deep-model

and

http://afeld.github.io/backbone-nested/

Which can be used instead

Comment: I haven't had major problems with using sub-collection on one go, I've used similar data structure - it's just not very well documented.

Answer (score 0):

```
items.fetch();
 console.log(items.toJSON());
```

Collection.fetch() is an asynchronous operation. It won't produce a response until the request gets back from the server. Try this:

```
items.fetch().done(function(){
    console.log(items.toJSON());
});
```

You can also use the web inspector in safari/chrome (or firefox debugger / firebug) to monitor network requests and see that your calls are firing successfully (and inspect the responses), or put another console.log statement inside the 'parse' function of your collection.

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

Comment: It didn't help, I still get empty array